# How to trigger useEffect in React only once AFTER some certain variable gets loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to use useEffect hook in React to trigger some functions only once. I know that this could normally be done by doing

```
useEffect(() => {
    // some functions
    }
}, [])
```

However, the functions require some values to be loaded. So, I only want this useEffect to get triggered only ONCE when the value is not empty.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // some functions
}, [theValue])
```

This is what I tried, but I know that this will get triggered whenever `theValue` changes.

How can I change my useEffect to run only ONCE when `theValue` becomes not empty?

Comment: By "loaded" are you talking about an async request?

Comment: without any other info... what you could do is a third state that will "filter" everything after the first call... something inside useEffect like `if (firstTime) do stuff else dont`

Comment: `useEffect` is essentially discouraged. See react docs [*You might not need an effect*](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#initializing-the-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a React ref to hold a boolean if the effect has been triggered yet, and combine that with a conditional test that all the dependencies have been met to trigger the effect.

```
const effectTriggeredRef = React.useRef(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!effectTriggeredRef.current && /* deps conditions */) {
    effectTriggeredRef.current = true;
    // trigger some functions
  }
}, [...deps]);
```